# What is Xcache's maximum var cache size?

Tags: php, xcache

We would like to make use of xCache 3.0.3's variable prefixing in order to provide xCache's varcache on shared hosting.

Our server has got 256GB of memory and we would idealy like to dedicate about 30GB to xCache.

However anything over 1024MB and PHP crashes on startup and we seem to need to keep xCache's total cache size limit around 600MB to not crash when it's full.

Our server has 32 CPU threads so we initially set xcache.count to 32 and xcache total size to 1024MB. Following some PHP crashes related to xCache we reduced the number of xcache.count to 16 and the total cache to 600MB, everything is now running smoothly but withw varcache.

What is limiting us here ? Is it an operating system limit ? Is it xCache that just isn't built for managing this much memory ? Is it beacause of too many slots ?

If we set xcache count to 16 and xcache total memory to 4096MB creating 16 cache stores of 256MB should this be an issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best thing here might be to contact the xcache developer on the official support google group channel, he might be of more help:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/xcache

Apart from that, maybe try memcached ?